# What is poling interval of Monitored Deployment in IBM WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

What is poling interval of Monitored Deployment in  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Is it enabled by default?
How do we enable it manually.

How can we alter the directory with the help of WSADMIN

Does changing any configuration related to it need a server recycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can use the monitored directory application deployment service, you must enable it. You can optionally change the default monitored directory and polling interval values. By default, the monitored directory application deployment service is not enabled, the monitored directory is app_server_root/monitoredDeployableApps, and the polling interval is 5 seconds.

You can use an administrative console or wsadmin scripting to enable or disable monitored directory deployment and change the monitored directory and polling interval.

A monitoredDirectoryDeployment object has the following attributes:

Procedure

```
Use the Global deployment settings page of an administrative console to set monitored directory values.
    Click Applications > Global deployment settings.
    To enable monitored directory deployment, select Monitor directory to automatically deploy applications.

    To disable monitored directory deployment, clear Monitor directory to automatically deploy applications.
    To change the monitored directory path, specify a new value for Monitored directory.

    Ensure that the directory that you specified for Monitored directory exists. The product does not create the directory for you.
    To change the polling interval, specify the number of seconds for Polling interval.
    Click Apply.
    If you are using an administrative console for a base (stand-alone) application server to change monitored directory values, restart the application server.

    If you are using an administrative console for a deployment manager to change monitored directory values, restart the deployment manager.
```

You can visit IBM page for more..

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

for Monitored Deployments, default value is '5' seconds.

you can Modify it from "Global Deployment Settings" from the left side Navigation Panel.

for more info, go thru this excellent link, 
http://webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/WebSphere%208%20Auto%20Deploy

Answer (score 1):

Monitored Deployment is not enabled by default. Default value for poling interval is 5 seconds. To enable monitored deployment, you have to set to value of enable monitored directory deployment to "**true**". Perform below steps to enable it from console.

Click on 
**Applications > Global deployment settings**
then
select **Monitor directory to automatically deploy applications** to enable monitored deployment.

1. start wsadmin
2. set cell context value

**myCell = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:WASCell01/')**

3. set monitor deployment attribute using cell context value

**monitorDirectory = AdminConfig.showAttribute(myCell, "monitoredDirectoryDeployment")**

4. set new path using below jython command

**AdminConfig.modify(monitorDirectory, [['monitoredDirectory', "/NewPath/Which/YouWantToUse/"]])**

5. Then save configuration changes done using below command

**AdminConfig.save()**

It requires Deployment manager restart in network deployment environment. for stand alone environment you have to restart your server.